# Populating Bridge tables

Tags: sql, database-design, ssis

Hello I have a bridge table that has these two columns only to carry the IDs from other dim tables
I'm wondering how can I populate this bridge table and make it related because a simple insert into a statement won't match the productId to the correct SupplierID

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join`s:

```
select p.productid, s.supplierid
from stageTable st join
     products p
     on st.product = p.product join
     suppliers s
     on st.suppliername = s.suppliername;
```

You can put `insert into . . .` before this for the insert.